# SVS.Build should not specify a version

Tags: visual-studio

Sitecore Visual Studio Project

The package reference 'SVS.Build' should not specify a version.  Please specify the version in 'xxx\Packages.props' or set VersionOverride to override the centrally defined version.

I have already added to nuget.config

```
<add key='SVSComponents' value='https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-developer-collection/api/v3/index.json'/>
```

**how to resolve ????????**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to Right click on the Sitecore Visual Studio Project, Manage Nuget Packages and add SVS Build ...

ONLY THEN DID IT ACTUALLY ADD THE package.config !!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. unload your Myproject.build
2. remove the version from you SVS.Build reference

   `<PackageReference Include="SVS.Build"> </PackageReference>`
3. Add the following version update to your **Packages.props:**

   `<PackageReference Update="SVS.Build" Version="1.0.0.10"/>`